# not able to shuffle a JSONArray

Tags: java, android

I am trying to shuffle a JSONArray and a get a subset(JSONArray). So for example if my JSONArray has 5 entries, I want to generate a JSONArray with random 3 entries out of 5 in it. 
Below is the code for shuffling the JSONArray. Problem is that the output JSONArray has backslash() characters introduced before every occurance of double quotes("). Not sure why is this hapening. Any help from someone. Also any suggestions on how can i pick first 3 random entries of 5 from a JSONArray

```
public JSONArray getRandomJSONArray(JSONArray jArray){
    List<String> stringArrayMaster = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(jArray.toString()));
    Collections.shuffle(stringArrayMaster);
    JSONArray randomJArray = new JSONArray(stringArrayMaster);
    return randomJArray;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to do it. below is the code. Note that the variable numQuestions contain integer value for the size of the array subset I need. So it jArray.length() is 5 then numQuestions is 3(any number less than jArray.length().

```
JSONArray shuffled = new JSONArray();   
    ArrayList<Integer> intArr1=new ArrayList<Integer>(jArray.length());
    for(int i = 0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
        intArr1.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(intArr1);
    for(int i = 0; i < intArr1.size(); i++){
        shuffled.put(i, jArray.get(intArr1.get(i)));
        if (i==(numQuestions-1))
                break;
    }
    return shuffled;
```

Answer (score 0):

The \ is added because a " in JSON has a special meaning-  its the end of the field.  So to have a " in a string you need to escape it.  \ is used for that escaping.  As for getting the first 3 entries-  jsonArray.getString(0); jsonArray.getString(1); jsonArray.getString(2);  As a bonus these should be unescaped, since JSONArray knows java doesn't need the escape

Comment: In my code above jArray.toString() does not have any \ in it. But when I do randomArray.toString(), i see \ in it. If the toString operation inserts the escape character then why does jArray.toString() not have it. Also regarding the first 3 entries, I actually meant first three random entries from the JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just manually get 3 random entries from your JSONArray? Assuming the JSONArray is made up of JSONObjects you could do the following

```
JSONArray shuffled = new JSONArray();
Random r = new Random();
int size = jArray.length();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    shuffled.put(jArray.getJSONObject(r.nextInt(size - 1)));
}
return shuffled;
```

My idea is to just to create a new JSONArray that will hold the random entries. Generate a random number within the bounds of your jArray (0 and the size of the array - 1) and then get the object correspnding to that index value and add it to your new shuffled collection.

This would not add any escape characters to the mix.

Comment: Good suggestion. I tested this just now. I however saw one value being repeated in Jsonarray 'shuffled'. Not sure why. So for example my jarray was say ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] then a random array `shuffle` of length 4 had values ["b", "b", "c", "d"]. My jArray is indeed made of JSONObjects

Comment: Ah - I did not realize you wanted to add and not repeat values. Picking x random values out of 5 does have the chance that some will be repeated. Would have just added a conditional to check the last added and not double. Glad you figured it out anyway.